# Run html tag script in Webview

Tags: android, html, facebook, webview

I have a service that returns a html code to render on a webview in my app, sometimes it returns a youtube embed, istagram or facebook, but the facebook is the only one is not working.

```
"<script async=\"1\" defer=\"1\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" src=\"https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v8.0\" nonce=\"dUFa7MFK\"></script><div class=\"fb-video\" data-href=\"https://www.facebook.com/terradememe/videos/222040112417866\"><blockquote cite=\"https://www.facebook.com/terradememe/videos/222040112417866/\" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\"><a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/terradememe/videos/222040112417866/\">Algumas histórias assustadoras!</a><p>Algumas histórias assustadoras!\n"
```

Here is only a part of the body, on facebook video we put it on a `script` tag and when I play the video the app freeze and do nothing, but if I press on back button the app return it to normal behavior.

I saw a solution that use a `iframe` but in my case I need to work with `script`.

After a while I noticed this log:

```
"Refused to load the image 'android-webview-video-poster:default_video_poster/-1751309467915793562' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * data: blob: 'self'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."
```

Anyone have faced the same problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @Jyo yes, the problem here was the facebook API was returning a mobile link of the video. I had to change my code to allow fullscreen video.